# Implementing Deserialization of Objects

Tags: java, deserialization

As usual, I'm sure there is a multitude of answers out there to this question, however, I have no idea what to search to find them.

Say you have a bunch of animals, `Rat` `Cat` `Dog` and `Fish`, and you want to serialize/deserialize these animals. Each has its own `serialize()` method. That all works fine and good, if you want to save your Cat to a file, you call `Cat.serialize()` and then you write it to a file.

But what about deserializing? Sure, you could save an extra bit of data that states the type of animal, then use reflection to get a static method (say, `deserialize(String serialized)`) and then invoke it. But that's not safe. What if someone creates a new animal 'Rabbit' and doesn't include a `deserialize(String serialized)` method? Sure, you could then just catch the error and ignore the issue, but that seems unclean and bad practice.

You could also create an enum. Each item in the enum must have a `deserialize(String serialized)` method, and the aforementioned piece of data that states the type references the name of its enum item. Very clean. Problem is, not very adaptable. Enums don't allow for other animals to be added at runtime.

The way I have been solving this issue is mapping the name of the objects against a deserializer object. Basically each animal would have to 'register' itself by entering it's name and deserializer (implements `Deserializer` interface) object into a HashMap. The deserializer object can then be retrieved via the name of the animal at a later time.

My question is, what is the best method to go about implementing deserialization? Also, is the method I have been using good/bad practice?

Finally, if you are wondering why animals would be added at runtime, the reason is because animals might be added by other non accessible parts of the program, or by things such as plugins.

---

Example of the method I have been using is below.

**Animal Interface**

```
public class Animal{
    public String serialize();
}
```

**Deserializer Interface**

```
public interface Deserializer{
    public Animal deserialize();
}
```

**Deserializer Storer:**

```
public class AnimalSpecies{
    public static final String DELIMITER="|";
    private static HashMap<String,GameModeType> species=new HashMap<String,GameModeType>();
    public static addSpecies(String speciesName,Deserializer deserializer){
        if (species.contains(speciesName)){
            //Throw error
        }
        species.put(speciesName,deserializer);
    }
    public static Deserializer getSpeciesDeserializer(String speciesName){
        return species.get(speciesName);
    }
}
```

**Cat class**

```
public class Cat implements Animal{
    public static  final String DELIMITER=AnimalSpecies.DELIMITER;
    private String type;
    private int age;
    private String name;
    public static register(){
        AnimalSpecies.addSpecies("CAT",new deserializer());
    }
    public Cat(String name,String type,Int age){
        this.type=type;
        this.age=age;
        this.name=name;
    }
    public String serialize(){
        return "CAT"+DELIMITER+type+DELIMITER+age+DELIMITER+name;
    }
    private static class deserializer implements Deserializer{
        @Override
        public Cat deserialize(String serialized){
            String[] split=serialized.split(DELIMITER);
            return new Cat(split[3].split[1],Integer.parseInt(split[2]));
        }
    }
}
```

Then in you main method you would call:

```
Cat.register();
```

And when you needed to deserialize:

```
    Deserializer d=AnimalSpecies.getSpeciesDeserializer(serialized.split(AnimalSpecies.DELIMITER)[0]);
    if (d!=null){
        d.deserialize(serialized);
    }
```

After writing all this out, I cant help but notice how much my method requires cooperation/understanding from other parties. It cant be guaranteed that the correct delimiter will be used. What I mean by this is that any serialized Animal must have a way of identifying which animal it is so that it's deserializer can be accessed. This can be worked around by implementing a wrapper that adds this information directly before it is written to a file, and removes it directly before deserialization.

---

**Why not use built in serialization/deserialization?**

I would like the serialized data to be readable and easily editable.

Comment: Why would someone not have a `deserialize` for `Rabbit`?

Comment: "_is the method I have been using good/bad practice?_" Why not add code? This is pretty abstract IMHO.

Comment: @OrhanC1 If a separate party is using your code, it can not be guaranteed. That's why interfaces are so useful. It means you can guarantee that certain objects will have certain methods. There isn't however, such a thing for static methods, and therein lies the issue.

Comment: @Unihedron Point taken. Problem is, it requires a few classes, but I'll do my best.

Comment: If you don't include the `deserialize` method then your class hierarchy is wrong, because it should be an interface on a superclass. Like, `Serializable`. Which already exists in Java in the form of `java.io.Serializable` with which you can de/serialize objects using `ObjectInputStream`/`ObjectOutputStream`.

Comment: @Zhuinden That would mean the `deserialize` method would not be static. This makes no sense as it would require an instance of the object being created which is... well, paradoxical.

`ObjectInputStream`/`ObjectOutputStream` outputs bytes. I am intending to serialize in a manner that is both readable and editable.

Comment: Then use an XML or JSON serializer. They tend to just use the Class<?> of the given class to obtain the information, then serialize all data. Configuration is done with annotations. SimpleXML is a good example.

Comment: Why does it matter that the "correct" delimiter is used, since each subclass is responsible for its own serialization format?

Comment: @JamieCockburn The delimiter I was referring to is the one that indicates the break between species of the animal and its data, and thus the animal name, and thus the deserializer to use.
EG: `CAT|tabby|5|mittens`
When the serialized data is split and the first section is take we get "CAT" which will point to the cat's deserializer.

If the wrong delimiter is used: `CAT,tabby,5,mittens`
we get "CAT,tabby,5,mittens" which wont point to any deserializer.

Comment: @Zwander aye, but since you're using that delimiter outside of `Cat`, why does it matter if `Dog` serializes as `I'm a DoG + rover : labrador + 12`?  Since it's up to `Dog` how it does it's own (de)serialization in your scheme.

Comment: @JamieCockburn How do you know that `I'm a DoG + rover : labrador + 12` is a Dog?

Comment: @Zhuinden Correct me if I'm wrong, but I feel that it would be a little excessive to use and XML or JSON library for a simple thing such as this. Regardless, I would still like to know the correct method of doing this as it is not the only case where you need multiple classes to have consistent static methods (or something to that effect).

Comment: Java comes with built-in support for serialization.  Have you considered using this?  For which reason did you not choose to use this?

Comment: @JimN Readability/editability. I will append my post to include this.

Comment: Think about it. The deserialize() method has to be static, as it has to construct a new object: therefore it can't be defined in an interface.

Comment: You want it to be readable and editable. XML and JSON seems like the easiest way to achieve that.